# React router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hello when I try to get data from a file. The react app goes blank. Here is what I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import articles from "./article-content";

const ArticlePage = () =>{
const { name } = useParams();
const { article } = articles.find(article => article.name === name)

return(
<>
    <div id="page-body">
        <h1>{article.title}</h1>
        <h1>{article.content}</h1>
    </div>
</>
);
}
export default ArticlePage;
```

and here is example of the article-content:

```
const articles = [
{
    name: 'learn-react',
    title: 'The Fastest Way to Learn React',
    content: [.....
]]
export default articles;
```

Any ideas why it's going blank instead of rendering?

Comment: Is `ArticlePage` rendered by a `Route` component with a `path` prop specifying a `name` route match param? In other words, can you update your question to include how `ArticlePage` is being rendered? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, in your example `articles` array I don't see where any of the element objects have an `article` property to destructure, and the code needs to handle `Array.prototype.find` possibley returning `undefined` which would throw an error if you attempt to destructure from it. Perhaps you meant, `const article = articles.find(...)`? Even so, if no matching article is found the code would throw error when trying to access `title` and `content` of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chrome's  console to have a clue of what is happening with your app. Press F12 or right click on your Chrome and open the Inspector, and then go to the "Console" tab. It will be your best tool for debugging your apps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Please change the below lines from
const { name } = useParams();
const { article } = articles.find(article => article.name === name)

to
const name = useParams();
const article = articles.find(article => article.name === name)

you cannot able to destructure it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).